# Dynamically append each values into 2D slice

Tags: arrays, go, append, slice

I wish to have a datastructure(array or slice) to look like this :

```
[[a b c d e][f g h i j] [k l m n o] [p q r s t] [u v w x y]]
```

such that a is the distance between node from "A" to "A" . (which shall be 0)
b is the distance between node from "A" to "B" .
c is the distance between node from "A" to "C" .

f is the distance between node from "B" to "A" .
g is the distance between node from "B" to "B" . (which shall be 0)
h is the distance between node from "B" to "C" .

Now I have created a slice like  : 
`var shortestPathSLice = make([][]int, 5)` to store this 2D data.

In my for loop within a function, I am trying to fill this slice dynamically as follows :

```
shortestPathSLice = append(shortestPathSLice[0][index], lowEstimate[0])
```

where lowestimate[0] is value of the smallest distances between two nodes.

However, I get an error with this : **first argument to append must be slice; have int**

**Can anyone tell me how can I dynamically append values in EACH ELEMENT in my slice ?**

**CODE **

```
    var shortestPathSLice = make([][]int, 5)
    for index := 0; index < len(t.Location_ids); index++ {
    lowEstimate := make([]int, len(priceestimatestruct.Prices))
        for i := 0; i < len(priceestimatestruct.Prices); i++ {
            lowEstimate[i] = priceestimatestruct.Prices[i].LowEstimate
        }

        sort.Ints(lowEstimate)
        fmt.Println("LowEstimate array : ", lowEstimate)
        shortestPathSLice[0] = make([]int, len(lowEstimate))
        shortestPathSLice[0][index] = lowEstimate[0]
}
```

Comment: `shortestPathSLice` is a 2d array of type `[][]int`. So `shortestPathSLice[0][index]` selects the int at `0.index`. The first arg for append must however be a slice, so either your `0` of `index` should be omitted.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is: `shortestPathSLice[0][index] = lowEstimate[0]`. That would assign int? `lowEstimate[0]` to slice index `0.index`.

Comment: @RickyA Thanks for replying .For 1st iteration, My LowEstimate array is :  [6 12 12 18 27] and I want shortestPathSLice as [[0 6 0 0 0]] 
For 2nditeration, My LowEstimate array is :  [35 37 38 39] and I want shortestPathSLice as [[0 6 35 0 0]]

Comment: Ok, that means that you should go with `shortestPathSLice[0][index] = lowEstimate[0]` in your inner loop.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://gobyexample.com/slices) page for initializing 2d slices

Comment: @RickyA , I tried that before using append method but it gave me error like http: panic serving [::1]:49897: runtime error: index out of range

Comment: Yes, you need two `make` statements here. That panic is caused because the inner slice is not initialized yet. `make([][]int, 5)` creates this: `[[]int,[]int,[]int,[]int,[]int]`, not `[[int,int,int,int,int]]`

Comment: @RickyA , So I made shortestPathSLice[index] = make([]int, len(lowEstimate)); shortestPathSLice[0][index] = lowEstimate[0]  but it still gave me index out of range error :( Anything you feel I am missing ?

Comment: I think that should be `shortestPathSLice[0] = make([]int, len(lowEstimate))`, since `index` is not always 0. Can you show your code, I think you have some structural errors there.

Comment: var shortestPathSLice = make([][]int, 5)
lowEstimate := make([]int, len(priceestimatestruct.Prices))
 for i := 0; i < len(priceestimatestruct.Prices); i++ {
  lowEstimate[i] = priceestimatestruct.Prices[i].LowEstimate
 }

 sort.Ints(lowEstimate)
 fmt.Println("LowEstimate array : ", lowEstimate)
 shortestPathSLice[0] = make([]int, len(lowEstimate))
 shortestPathSLice[0][index] = lowEstimate[0]

Comment: I am sorry , I dont have enough reputations to chat with you :(  I am adding code in the question

Comment: I am missing the outer loop and declaration of `shortestPathSLice`

Answer (score 4):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Appending to and copying slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> The built-in functions append and copy assist in common slice
>   operations. For both functions, the result is independent of whether
>   the memory referenced by the arguments overlaps.
>
> The variadic function append appends zero or more values x to s of
>   type S, which must be a slice type, and returns the resulting slice,
>   also of type S. The values x are passed to a parameter of type ...T
>   where T is the element type of S and the respective parameter passing
>   rules apply. As a special case, append also accepts a first argument
>   assignable to type []byte with a second argument of string type
>   followed by .... This form appends the bytes of the string.
>
> ```
> append(s S, x ...T) S  // T is the element type of S
> ```
>
> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values,
>   append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits
>   both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise,
>   append re-uses the underlying array.

For example, using `append` and using an index,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    { // using append
        dim := 5
        matrix := make([][]int, dim) // dim*dim matrix
        for i := 0; i < dim; i++ {
            matrix[i] = make([]int, 0, dim)
            vector := make([]int, dim)
            for j := 0; j < dim; j++ {
                vector[j] = i*dim + j
                matrix[i] = append(matrix[i], vector[j])
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(matrix)
    }
    { // using index
        dim := 5
        matrix := make([][]int, dim) // dim*dim matrix
        for i := range matrix {
            matrix[i] = make([]int, dim)
            vector := make([]int, dim)
            for j := range matrix[i] {
                vector[j] = i*dim + j
                matrix[i][j] = vector[j]
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(matrix)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8 9] [10 11 12 13 14] [15 16 17 18 19] [20 21 22 23 24]]
[[0 1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8 9] [10 11 12 13 14] [15 16 17 18 19] [20 21 22 23 24]]
```